# $A'$ Set Of All Accumulation Points Is Closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq M$, and $A'$ is the set of all accumulation points

Prove: $A'$ is closed

Let $a\in M$ and $x_n\in A'$ such that $x_n\to a$, we shall show that $a\in A'$

let $U$ be a neighborhood of $a$, so it has some points of $x_n$, lets take one of them $b=x_{n_0}$ so $U$ is also neighborhood of $b$ so there are infinite points of $A$ and therefore $a\in A'$

We can we conclude that there are infinite point in $U$ and there for $a\in A'$?

Comment: Your reasoning is sound, but the presentation is less good. I am thinking primarily of the statement “there are infinite points of $A$”. We don't think of any points of a general metric space as infinite, so that makes no sense. Surely, what you meant to say is that $U$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. A similar remark applies to your final sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good, but the exposition should be improved.

You want to prove that every neighborhood of $a$ contains points of $A$ distinct from $a$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$; by convergence, there is $n$ such that $d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon/2$.

Since $x_n\in A'$ by assumption, there are infinitely many points $b$ of $A$ such that $d(b,x_n)<\varepsilon/2$, in particular a point $b_0$ of $A$ distinct from $x_n$ *and* $a$ such that $d(b_0,x_n)<\varepsilon/2$.

Then $d(b_0,a)\le d(b_0,x_n)+d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- $x_n\in A'\implies \exists a_n\in A \:\text{such}\:\text{that}\: d(x_n,a_n)<\dfrac1n.$
- $d(a_n,a)\le d(x_n,a)+\dfrac1n.$